# Silverlight autocomplete textbox control?

Tags: silverlight, autocomplete

Is there a control in Silverlight which act like the TO text box in email composers 
which when you start typing it gives you a list of contacts and when select one and start type again will give you the contact list to select another email address (multi email addresses selection)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the [`AutoCompleteBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.autocompletebox%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

You set up an `ItemsSource` to be the possible e-mail addresses and when the user starts typing it will search against this list and suggest matches. So in your scenario you'd need to read the address book to populate this list.

You don't have to bind to a list of strings, it allows you to bind to an object and display and match against the human readable representation of that object.